# How to resize PNG image to specified size (kb)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

With jpg image, i can do this for resize image length to 200kb:

```
$imagickObject->setOption('jpeg:extent', "200kb");
```

But i can't found solution for png image.

```
$imagickObject->setOption('png:extent', "200kb"); not work
```

Anyone have a solution?

Please help.

Comment: The only way with PNG is to iterative resize in dimensions until you reach the desired file size.

Comment: @fmw42 Or iteratively reducing the number of colours to next lower power of 2 may also be a possibility?

Comment: @Mark Setchell Possible, if saving as palette PNG8. But you might as well just use GIF if you want to reduce colors.

Comment: @fmw42 In OP's case though, they want PNG, so I was saying that the only way to get a smaller PNG is either by reducing the pixel dimensions as you suggested, or reducing the number of colours so that the resulting PNG becomes smaller because the row filtering should result in something more compressible because there will be fewer differences hen there are fewer colours and also a smaller palette.

Answer (score 5):

**TLDR**; If saving as PNG rather than JPEG, you have to iteratively use your skill and judgement to decide yourself what to compromise on in order to make your file smaller.

**Longer Explanation**

The reason preventing you from doing what you're trying to do is that JPEG is designed for real-life photographs, JPEG = *"Joint Photographic Experts Group"*. It makes tradeoffs in picture quality in order to be able to fit lots of photos on memory cards and disks and to be able to transmit images fast across networks. It is **lossy** - it is allowed to discard quality.

PNG is designed more for presentation graphics and computer-generated diagrams with blocks of solid colour rather than nuanced details of real-life objects. It is **loss-less** and *there's the rub* - it cannot discard details to save space.

So, you have fewer choices with PNG - you pretty much have to choose what compromises you are going to make.

---

As Fred (fmw42) rightly says in the comments, one way to discard information is to reduce the image dimensions. So, let's look at this image which is a 240kB JPEG attributed to Chris Niccolls from [here](https://www.dpreview.com/sample-galleries/0739659306/om-system-om-1-sample-gallery/1478125439):

[image]

So, if I make that into a full-colour PNG, it comes out at 973kB:

```
magick owl.jpg owl.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   973K 21 Feb 11:05 owl.png
```

And, if I reduce the dimensions by 50%, it comes out at 318kB:

```
magick owl.jpg -resize 50% owl.png
-rw-r--r--     1 mark  staff   318K 21 Feb 11:06 owl.png
```

---

Another way to make it smaller is to reduce colour resolution rather than spatial resolution, i.e. reduce number of colours rather than number of pixels. So, I can reduce the colours to 127, or 63, or 31 or 15 like this:

```
magick owl.jpg -colors 127 PNG8:owl-127.png
magick owl.jpg -colors 63 PNG8:owl-63.png
magick owl.jpg -colors 31 PNG8:owl-31.png
magick owl.jpg -colors 15 PNG8:owl-15.png
```

And that reduces the sizes as follows:

```
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   368K 21 Feb 10:40 owl-255.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   329K 21 Feb 10:38 owl-127.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   252K 21 Feb 10:38 owl-63.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   225K 21 Feb 10:38 owl-31.png
-rw-r--r--@    1 mark  staff   171K 21 Feb 10:42 owl-15.png
```

It also affects picture quality like this. The leftmost image has the most colours, the rightmost the fewest. Try focussing in on the area just below the bird's tail in the leftmost and rightmost images to see the difference most readily:

[image]

---

Another possible tradeoff you can make is to spend longer creating the file in return for a smaller file. That is the approach used by `pngcrush`. It takes the image and tries all possible methods of filtering and encoding that are permissible under the PNG standard and finds the one that results in the smallest file. Use it like this:

```
pngcrush -brute  owl-255.png owl-crushed.png

Total length of data found in critical chunks            =    333281
Best pngcrush method        =   7 (ws 15 fm 0 zl 9 zs 0) =    327985
```

So that saved 5kB - YMMV.

No owls were crushed or otherwise hurt whilst creating this answer.

Comment: Nice discussion, Mark!