# Lossless Image compression in python using Open CV or any other modules

Tags: python, opencv, lossless-compression

I want to perform lossless compression on the image [Example image attached here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TFagS5_4QIwDTMV5WdfImIJs6vmUNxsI/view?usp=sharing). It is a 16 bit image of 1024*1024.

I realized that lossless compression is possible using PNG format with Open CV. Open CV allows compression using a compression attribute, which can be set between 0 to 9 to vary the compression. But the compression is not much. Below is the code that I used and screenshot of file sizes of actual image, image compressed with value 9 and image compressed with value 0.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import os, cv2, sys

actual_image_in_png_format = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'actual_image.png')

src = cv2.imread(actual_image_in_png_format,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.imwrite("PNG_COMPRESSION_9.png", src, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 9])
cv2.imwrite("PNG_COMPRESSION_0.png", src, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
```

[image]

My question is that, is it possible to get a higher lossless compression using Open CV or any other python modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might like to have a read here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205362/2836621

Comment: The image you have shared is an 8-bit JPEG not a 16-bit PNG !!! Please share an actual, representative image - possibly using Dropbox or Google Drive if necessary.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I have updated the link to actual image in the question. Thanks for the hint. Same link I'm copying here  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TFagS5_4QIwDTMV5WdfImIJs6vmUNxsI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thanks a lot for the link. I'll check that and see if it helps my case

Comment: @MarkSetchell: From the link I see that spatial and color methods are lossy. Hence I cannot use it. Please correct me if I am wrong. And the pngcrush method doesn't reduce the image size by much ;( But your answer in that question was very very useful information. Thanks

Comment: Your image is noisy so lossless compression will always give poor results, whatever the method. If I am right, the levels in PNG correspond to speed of decompression, and have little to do with the compression ratio.

Comment: It is in fact so noisy, that the low order bits are random and converting to 8 bits would be harmless.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks for the info. But how could I check that the low order bits are noisy. I am a bit new to this. Any links or suggestions would help. Note: If reduced to 8 bit jpg, I was able to get an [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yKaNOIhUL9-dGNtxovTkEo5ian_kcirc/view?usp=sharing) with only 100kb(using scikit) and I couldn't find any difference in image quality between 1.8MB png image and 100kb jpg image, with bare eyes.

Comment: You see the noise by naked eyes. What matters is what you plan to do with those images. If just to archive them and never look at them, any compression method will do ;-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust The levels in PNG are the same as in ZLIB. They determine how hard the compressor looks for matches in the sliding window. The effect on decompression speed is negligible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: The image is taken and stored by an application, running in a Linux system. And the allowed storage space to store the images is only 2GB. Due to which we need to compress the images if possible. If the image size is reduced, it would help us store more number of images.

Comment: Compress, or maybe transfer elsewhere? Surely the machine is connected to a network?

Comment: How does that tell me what you do with the images ?

Comment: You may consider JPEG2000 compression, but it looks like there is a bug in OpenCV 16 bits JPEG2000 compression. I tried FFmpeg CLI lossless compression: `ffmpeg -i actual_image.png -vcodec libopenjpeg actual_image.jp2`. but the files size is only about 10% smaller than the PNG. You may also try lossy JPEG2000 compression: `ffmpeg -y -i actual_image.png -vcodec libopenjpeg -compression_level 2 actual_image.jp2`.