# Is it possible to compress PNGs like tinyPNG/PngQuant with Php-gd/imagemagick/intervention?

Tags: php, imagemagick, intervention, php-gd

Is it possible to compress PNGs with results similar to TinyPNG/PngQuant in regards to size reduction and quality retention, using vanilla PHP tools like PHP/GD, PHP/Imagemagick and/or intervention/image? TinyPng/PngCompression can sometimes reduce 90% of image size without losing enough quality to be noticed by normal users.

I already tried econding with 70% quality with intervention:

```
 $img = $img->encode('png', 70);
```

But image size is aways more than the double of what i get compressing it in TinyPng. Installing quantPng in the server isn't always possible or easy, that's why i would like to know if similar results can be obtained without having to install it.

Comment: Maybe have a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205362/2836621

Comment: The way some of these optimization tools work is to try every possible PNG compression value and keep the result from the best.