# reduced image color is bigger while except smaller

Tags: opencv, image-processing, compression, image-compression

I'm reduce a 256 bit image colors with following function:

```
def reduce(image,quantize_val=32):
    img_reduced=(image//quantize_val) * quantize_val + quantize_val//2
    return img_reduced
```

when I save that using:

```
cv2.imwrite("reduced.jpg",img_reduced)
```

It is even bigger than first image, and cv2 save it as 24bit which is wrong, how can I force cv2 that save image with 9 bits for example?

Comment: My understanding is that JPEG as a format presumes a certain bit width for each pixel. If you want your own custom format, you can certainly directly write the binary with whatever bit width you'd like by using `open("reduced.image", "wb").write(<binary bits>)`

Comment: @dsillman2000 didn't understand, could you give me an example? load an 24bit rgb image and reduce its color levels and then save it.

Comment: You don't reduce the size of a JPEG file by reducing the number of colors in the image. JPEG has a quality value. Reduce the value when saving, and you'll get a smaller file.

Comment: Here: `cv2.imwrite('name.jpg', img, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 50])`. The "50" there is a number between 0 and 100. The default is 95. Smaller values give smaller files (and worse quality image).

Comment: @CrisLuengo But in this assignment it wants to reduce size by reducing the number of colors. I successfully implemented the color reduction process but I don't know how to force it to save with my own bit depth.

Comment: Can't do that with JPEG. JPEG is always 24 bits. You might have misunderstood the assignment. Are you sure it expects a JPEG file, and not, say, a PNG file?

Comment: @CrisLuengo you mean that we can do this with png? the assignment doesn't say to save it with a specific format.

Comment: There's some relevant material here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205362/2836621